# Bluetooth LE Peripheral Role on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth

I'm doing a project where I need Windows 10 to act in the "Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral Role". It needs to advertise itself so that when someone comes by with a mobile device they can detect it, make a connection and interact with it, without needing to pair with it.
My problem is that the .NET BluetoothAdapter object's IsPeripheralRoleSupported is returning false.

I've tried googling to see if it should be supported in Windows 10, and to see if it is supported on my specific BT dongle. None of the BT dongles seem to indicate in their advertised specs whether "Peripheral Role" is supported. Most of them do say that "Low Energy" is supported.

When I check the device manager properties, it says 'false' under the "Bluetooth radio supports Low Energy Peripheral Role" (as per this post [https://www.howto-connect.com/see-if-windows-10-pc-supports-bluetooth-low-energy-peripheral-role/][1]), but I'm not sure if this might be because of the device, the driver, or if Windows 10 just doesn't support it at all.

Does anyone know if it is supported in Windows 10 and if so, do you know of a specific device that supports it?

This is the code I'm using to check:

```
        var localAdapter = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();
        ThrowIfNullAdapter(localAdapter);

        if (!localAdapter.IsPeripheralRoleSupported)
        {
            throw new Exception("Adapter does not support peripheral role");
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it is supporte dby the Windows 10. You have just find compatible Bluetooth adapter.

Answer (score 1):

To give some more context as I was also trying to figure this out. There are two Bluetooth LE Roles the hub, ie the central role, and the devices, ie the peripheral role.

Before Bluetooth 4.2 the roles were very separated and more than likely any device you find for laptops will only support the central roles. I have not found a transceiver that supports the peripheral roles. Those Bluetooth chips were received for headphones and such.

However after Bluetooth 4.2 apprently chips were able to support both roles. More recent laptops should have both.

If you want to be safe just buy an adapter with Bluetooth 5.0 and check to see if it works. I would like to point out that some OEM's mess with the LE Peripheral role before sending it out in laptops.

Comment: I can confirm that the peripheral role works on the Asus BT500 (it did not work on the BT400 I had before)